# Upload file to Google cloud storage from web client without user Authorize

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to allow my users upload images to my google cloud storage without the need to authorize.
I have google app engine server. And I want the upload done directly from the site.
I used the code below. what do I need to change? or mabye I need to do something in my keys ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * The Project ID of your Google Cloud Storage Project.
         */
        var PROJECT = 'abcd';
        /**
         * Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google Developers
         * Console on the "APIs & auth", "Credentials" page.
         * In your Developers Console project add a JavaScript origin
         * that corresponds to the domain from where you will be running the
         * script. For more info see:
         * https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2
         */
        var clientId = '701111116470-55bj2lkjlkkjkljhe97di22gus5hs3.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        /**
         * Enter the API key from the Google Developers Console, by following these
         * steps:
         * 1) Visit https://cloud.google.com/console and select your project
         * 2) Click on "APIs & auth" in the left column and then click “Credentials”
         * 3) Find section "Public API Access" and use the "API key." If sample is
         * being run on localhost then delete all "Referers" and save. Setting
         * should display "Any referer allowed." For more info see:
         * https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys
         */
        var apiKey = 'JHJhhguy8786875hghgjbS0nYjcMY';
        /**
         * To enter one or more authentication scopes, refer to the documentation
         * for the API.
         */
        var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control';
        /**
         * Constants for request parameters. Fill these values in with your custom
         * information.
         */
        var API_VERSION = 'v1';
        /**
         * Enter a unique bucket name to create a new bucket. The guidelines for
         * bucket naming can be found here:
         * https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming
         */
        //var BUCKET = 'code-sample-bucket-' + Date.now();
        var BUCKET = 'testbucket';
        /**
         * The name of the object inserted via insertObject method.
         */
        var object = "";
        /**
         * Get this value from the Developers Console. Click on the
         * “Cloud Storage” service in the Left column and then select
         * “Project Dashboard”. Use one of the Google Cloud Storage group IDs
         * listed and combine with the prefix “group-” to get a string
         * like the example below.
         */
        var GROUP =
                'group-kjhHJKHJKH897897878jgjghg8728f21c3ff22597efbfc63ccdb8f2294d8fd2561cb9';
        /**
         * Valid values are user-userId, user-email, group-groupId, group-email,
         * allUsers, allAuthenticatedUsers
         */
        var ENTITY = 'allUsers';
        /**
         * Valid values are READER, OWNER
         */
        var ROLE = 'READER';
        /**
         * Valid values are READER, OWNER
         */
        var ROLE_OBJECT = 'READER';
        /**
         * A list of example calls to the Google Cloud Storage JavaScript client
         * library, as well as associated explanations of each call.
         */
        var listApiRequestExplanations = {
            'listBuckets': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
            'for a list of buckets in your project, and returns the result as ' +
            'a list of Google Cloud Storage buckets.',
            'listObjects': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
            'for a list of objects in your bucket, and returns the result as ' +
            'a list of Google Cloud Storage objects.',
            'listBucketsAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
            'Storage API for the list of access control lists on buckets in your ' +
            'project and returns the result as a list of Google Cloud Storage ' +
            'Access Control Lists.',
            'listObjectsAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
            'Storage API for the list of access control lists on objects in your ' +
            'bucket and returns the result as a list of Google Cloud Storage ' +
            'Access Control Lists.',
            'getBucket': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
            'for a bucket in your project, and returns the result as a ' +
            'Google Cloud Storage bucket.',
            'getBucketAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
            'Storage API for the access control list on a specific bucket ' +
            'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',
            'getObjectAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
            'Storage API for the access control list on a specific object ' +
            'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',
            'insertBucket': 'This API call uses the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
            'to insert a bucket into your project.',
            'insertObject': 'This API call uses the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
            'to insert an object into your bucket.',
            'insertBucketAccessControls': 'This API uses the Google Cloud ' +
            'Storage API to insert an access control list on a specific bucket ' +
            'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',
            'insertObjectAccessControls': 'This API uses the Google Cloud ' +
            'Storage API to insert an access control list on a specific object ' +
            'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',
            'deleteBucket': 'This API uses the Google Cloud Storage API to delete ' +
            'an empty bucket and returns an empty response to indicate success.',
            'deleteObject': 'This API uses the Google Cloud Storage API to delete ' +
            'an object and returns an empty response to indicate success.'
        };
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of buckets in
         * your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function listBuckets() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.list({
                'project': PROJECT
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'listBuckets');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of objects in
         * your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function listObjects() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.objects.list({
                'bucket': BUCKET
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'listObjects');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the access control list on
         * a bucket in your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function listBucketsAccessControls() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.bucketAccessControls.list({
                'bucket': BUCKET
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'listBucketsAccessControls');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the access control list on
         * an object in your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function listObjectsAccessControls() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.objectAccessControls.list({
                'bucket': BUCKET,
                'object': object
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'listObjectsAccessControls');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve a bucket in
         * your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function getBucket() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.get({
                'bucket': BUCKET
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'getBucket');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve a bucket's Access Control
         * List in your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function getBucketAccessControls() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.bucketAccessControls.get({
                'bucket': BUCKET,
                'entity': GROUP
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'getBucketAccessControls');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve an object's Access Control
         * List in your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function getObjectAccessControls() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.objectAccessControls.get({
                'bucket': BUCKET,
                'object': object,
                'entity': GROUP
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'getObjectAccessControls');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert a bucket into
         * your Google Cloud Storage project.
         */
        function insertBucket() {
            resource = {
                'name': BUCKET
            };
            var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.insert({
                'project': PROJECT,
                'resource': resource
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'insertBucket');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an object into
         * your Google Cloud Storage bucket.
         */
        function insertObject(event) {
            try{
                var fileData = event.target.files[0];
            }
            catch(e) {
                //'Insert Object' selected from the API Commands select list
                //Display insert object button and then exit function
                filePicker.style.display = 'block';
                return;
            }
            const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
            const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
            const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
                var metadata = {
                    'name': fileData.name,
                    'mimeType': contentType
                };
                var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
                var multipartRequestBody =
                        delimiter +
                        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                        delimiter +
                        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
                        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
                        '\r\n' +
                        base64Data +
                        close_delim;
                //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
                //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
                //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
                var request = gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/upload/storage/' + API_VERSION + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                    },
                    'body': multipartRequestBody});
                //Remove the current API result entry in the main-content div
                listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content').childNodes;
                if (listChildren.length > 1) {
                    listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
                }
                try{
                    //Execute the insert object request
                    executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
                    //Store the name of the inserted object
                    object = fileData.name;
                }
                catch(e) {
                    alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
                }
            }
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an Access Control List into
         * your Google Cloud Storage bucket.
         */
        function insertBucketAccessControls() {
            resource = {
                'entity': ENTITY,
                'role': ROLE
            };
            var request = gapi.client.storage.bucketAccessControls.insert({
                'bucket': BUCKET,
                'resource': resource
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'insertBucketAccessControls');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an Access Control List into
         * your Google Cloud Storage object.
         */
        function insertObjectAccessControls() {
            resource = {
                'entity': ENTITY,
                'role': ROLE_OBJECT
            };
            var request = gapi.client.storage.objectAccessControls.insert({
                'bucket': BUCKET,
                'object': object,
                'resource': resource
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'insertObjectAccessControls');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to delete a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
         */
        function deleteBucket() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.delete({
                'bucket': BUCKET
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'deleteBucket');
        }
        /**
         * Google Cloud Storage API request to delete a Google Cloud Storage object.
         */
        function deleteObject() {
            var request = gapi.client.storage.objects.delete({
                'bucket': BUCKET,
                'object': object
            });
            executeRequest(request, 'deleteObject');
        }
        /**
         * Removes the current API result entry in the main-content div, adds the
         * results of the entry for your function.
         * @param {string} apiRequestName The name of the example API request.
         */
        function updateApiResultEntry(apiRequestName) {
            listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content')
                    .childNodes;
            if (listChildren.length > 1) {
                listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
            }
            if (apiRequestName != 'null') {
                window[apiRequestName].apply(this);
            }
        }
        /**
         * Determines which API request has been selected, and makes a call to add
         * its result entry.
         */
        function runSelectedApiRequest() {
            var curElement = document.getElementById('api-selection-options');
            var apiRequestName = curElement.options[curElement.selectedIndex].value;
            updateApiResultEntry(apiRequestName);
        }
        /**
         * Binds event listeners to handle a newly selected API request.
         */
        function addSelectionSwitchingListeners() {
            document.getElementById('api-selection-options')
                    .addEventListener('change',
                    runSelectedApiRequest, false);
        }
        /**
         * Template for getting JavaScript sample code snippets.
         * @param {string} method The name of the Google Cloud Storage request
         * @param {string} params The parameters passed to method
         */
        function getCodeSnippet(method, params) {
            var objConstruction = "// Declare your parameter object\n";
            objConstruction += "var params = {};";
            objConstruction += "\n\n";
            var param = "// Initialize your parameters \n";
            for (i in params) {
                param += "params['" + i + "'] = ";
                param += JSON.stringify(params[i], null, '\t');
                param += ";";
                param += "\n";
            }
            param += "\n";
            var methodCall = "// Make a request to the Google Cloud Storage API \n";
            methodCall += "var request = gapi.client." + method + "(params);";
            return objConstruction + param + methodCall;
        }
        /**
         * Executes your Google Cloud Storage request object and, subsequently,
         * inserts the response into the page.
         * @param {string} request A Google Cloud Storage request object issued
         *    from the Google Cloud Storage JavaScript client library.
         * @param {string} apiRequestName The name of the example API request.
         */
        function executeRequest(request, apiRequestName) {
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                var apiRequestNode = document.createElement('div');
                apiRequestNode.id = apiRequestName;
                var apiRequestNodeHeader = document.createElement('h2');
                apiRequestNodeHeader.innerHTML = apiRequestName;
                var apiRequestExplanationNode = document.createElement('div');
                apiRequestExplanationNode.id = apiRequestName + 'RequestExplanation';
                var apiRequestExplanationNodeHeader = document.createElement('h3');
                apiRequestExplanationNodeHeader.innerHTML = 'API Request Explanation';
                apiRequestExplanationNode.appendChild(apiRequestExplanationNodeHeader);
                var apiRequestExplanationEntry = document.createElement('p');
                apiRequestExplanationEntry.innerHTML =
                        listApiRequestExplanations[apiRequestName];
                apiRequestExplanationNode.appendChild(apiRequestExplanationEntry);
                apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiRequestNodeHeader);
                apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiRequestExplanationNode);
                var apiRequestCodeSnippetNode = document.createElement('div');
                apiRequestCodeSnippetNode.id = apiRequestName + 'CodeSnippet';
                var apiRequestCodeSnippetHeader = document.createElement('h3');
                apiRequestCodeSnippetHeader.innerHTML = 'API Request Code Snippet';
                apiRequestCodeSnippetNode.appendChild(apiRequestCodeSnippetHeader);
                var apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry = document.createElement('pre');
                //If the selected API command is not 'insertObject', pass the request
                //paramaters to the getCodeSnippet method call as 'request.wc.wc.params'
                //else pass request paramaters as 'request.wc.wc'


/*                if (apiRequestName != 'insertObject') {
                    apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry.innerHTML =
                            getCodeSnippet(request.wc.wc.method, request.wc.wc.params);
                    //Selected API Command is not 'insertObject'
                    //hide insert object button
                    filePicker.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry.innerHTML =
                            getCodeSnippet(request.wc.wc.method, request.wc.wc);
                }*/


                apiRequestCodeSnippetNode.appendChild(apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry);
                apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiRequestCodeSnippetNode);
                var apiResponseNode = document.createElement('div');
                apiResponseNode.id = apiRequestName + 'Response';
                var apiResponseHeader = document.createElement('h3');
                apiResponseHeader.innerHTML = 'API Response';
                apiResponseNode.appendChild(apiResponseHeader);
                var apiResponseEntry = document.createElement('pre');
                apiResponseEntry.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(resp, null, ' ');
                apiResponseNode.appendChild(apiResponseEntry);
                apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiResponseNode);
                var content = document.getElementById('main-content');
                content.appendChild(apiRequestNode);
            });
        }
        /**
         * Set required API keys and check authentication status.
         */
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        }
        /**
         * Authorize Google Cloud Storage API.
         */
        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: clientId,
                scope: scopes,
                immediate: true
            }, handleAuthResult);
        }
        /**
         * Handle authorization.
         */
        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
            var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                initializeApi();
                filePicker.onchange = insertObject;
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            }
        }
        /**
         * Handle authorization click event.
         */
        function handleAuthClick(event) {
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: clientId,
                scope: scopes,
                immediate: false
            }, handleAuthResult);
            return false;
        }
        /**
         * Load the Google Cloud Storage API.
         */
        function initializeApi() {
            gapi.client.load('storage', API_VERSION);
        }
        /**
         * Driver for sample application.
         */
        $(window)
                .bind('load', function() {
                    addSelectionSwitchingListeners();
                    handleClientLoad();
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
<button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
<header>
    <h1>Google Cloud Storage JavaScript Client Library Application</h1>
</header>
<label id="api-label">Try a sample API call!</label>
<select id="api-selection-options">
    <option value="null">
        Please select an example API call from the dropdown menu
    </option>
    <option value="listBuckets">
        List Buckets
    </option>
    <option value="insertBucket">
        Insert Bucket
    </option>
    <option value="getBucket">
        Get Bucket
    </option>
    <option value="getBucketAccessControls">
        Get Bucket Access Controls
    </option>
    <option value="insertBucketAccessControls">
        Insert Bucket Access Controls
    </option>
    <option value="listBucketsAccessControls">
        List Buckets Access Control List
    </option>
    <option value="insertObject">
        Insert Object
    </option>
    <option value="listObjects">
        List Objects
    </option>
    <option value="getObjectAccessControls">
        Get Object Access Controls
    </option>
    <option value="insertObjectAccessControls">
        Insert Object Access Controls
    </option>
    <option value="listObjectsAccessControls">
        List Objects Access Control List
    </option>
    <option value="deleteObject">
        Delete Object
    </option>
    <option value="deleteBucket">
        Delete Bucket
    </option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="file" id="filePicker" style="display: none" />
<div id="main-content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to generate_signed_url [google signed_url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), to allow users to upload to the cloud storage without need to authorize.

A very good working example is explanied here https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/uploading-files-google-cloud-storage/